# Swift 3: AVAudioPlayer not playing sound

Tags: swift, avplayer

I have a struct with my audio player in it:

```
struct MT_Audio {

    func playAudio(_ fileName:String, _ fileExtension:String,  _ atVolume:Float) {
        var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        if let  audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension) {
            let audioURL = URL(string:audioPath)
            do {
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
                audioPlayer.volume = atVolume
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}

//I'm calling it in viewDidLoad like this: 

    guard let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"heartbeat-01a", withExtension: "mp3") 
         else {
                print("can't find file")
                return
            }

       let myAudioPlayer = MT_Audio() //<--RESOLVED THE ISSUE BY MAKING THIS A PROPERTY OF THE VIEWCONTROLLER
       myAudioPlayer.playAudio("heartbeat-01a", "mp3", 1.0)
```

Since it doesn't crash and burn on the guard I know the file is there. I've also put a break point in after the try and I am getting to the audio player. When I go to the actual file and click on it in Xcode it plays. This fails on both the sim and device. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look to the right panel in Xcode. When the file is selected, the target membership should be checked. If not, check it and try again.

Comment: I had checked that before posting. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: _Side note_  you should avoid that this `implicit unwrapped optional`  that you have in `audioURL!`. Bundle.main provides a url method that returns a optional url use that instead `if let audioUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: fileExtension)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your `audioPlayer` is only stored within your `playAudio` function.

Try to keep the `audioPlayer` as an variable inside your class like this:

```
struct MT_Audio {

    var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

    mutating func playAudio(_ fileName:String, _ fileExtension:String,  _ atVolume:Float) {

        // is now member of your struct -> var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
        if let  audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: fileName, ofType: fileExtension) {
            let audioURL = URL(string:audioPath)
            do {
                let audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: audioURL!)
                audioPlayer.volume = atVolume
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Still not getting audio. Not sure why moving audioPlayer to a global variable within the struct would matter in regards to it playing the audio or not. I checked it in my code and it was instantiated. The file path is correct. The mp3 file plays when selected in Xcode. This is becoming a morning of grrrrr.

Comment: Got it working, you put me on the right track - see my comment above and changes to my code.